# Batch file "For /f" loops each folder twice and listing files twice

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file

This for loop loops through the files twice. why is it so? How can I modify this so that each .sql file is listed only once.

```
For /f %%G in ('dir /s /b "%ScriptsPath%" *.sql') do (
    echo "%%G"
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `dir` command is getting confused with the "*.sql" as a separate argument.  Try this instead.  This code assumes that your `ScriptsPath` variable does end in a backslash.

```
For /f %%G in ('dir /s /b "%ScriptsPath%*.sql"') do (
    echo "%%G"
)
```

Comment: I had to add an additional "\" to the path

Anyways Thanks Luke Z..You made my day!

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
    For /f %%G in ('dir /s /on /b "%ScriptsPath%\*.sql"') do (
    echo "%%G"
    )
```

I had to add an additional "\" to the path

Anyways Thanks Luke Z..You made my day!

Thanks & Regards
Vinayak